# RaspberryPi 2 UHS-III SD Card

Tags: raspbian, boot

I bought 16 GB and 32 GB micro SD and I have a problem:

Raspbian is booting properly but when I went to GUI, desktop wallpaper has been displayed, coursor started flickering, disk LED was blinking like crazy but after 5 minutes nothing happened, I was blocked...

I had UHS-I card and everything worked great but I lost it :/

I have 2 RPi2s, both has the same problem. What can I do ?

Comment: I've used a lot of crappy old cards on the Pi and still have to find one that gives up on me.  But there probably are unsupported/broken cards around.  I'd reformat the card properly (with the overwrite flag) with the [SD Card Tool](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/index.html), burn the image and run `raspi-config` to expand the filesystem.  If it still crashes after this, your card probably is due for replacement.

Comment: But it's just not able to start GUI :/

Comment: I can expand filesystem, I can create python script on desktop I can run it, I can do everything in console byt GUI is not working..

Comment: On both cards and RPis.

Comment: Have you tried to download and burn disk image once more? Have you tried any other OS?

Comment: I wanted to have clear Raspbian :/ Without NOOBS it wasn't working but now (Raspbian installed with NOOBS) it is :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather from your comments, I would suggest to re-download the rasbian image, reformat the SD cards (back up what you need first) and try again.

Comment: Tried 3 times, I had to use NOOBS :/ Clear image should work, and It was but without GUI, weird...

Comment: Very specific rarities like this are usually related to something that got corrupted on the SD card or image. You should also check your power supply. It might sound strange but if your Pi doesn't get enough power it will misbehave in the strangest ways and your SD card might get corrupted as well. You need 5V 2A and a not-too-long USB cable (long or bad quality cables make for power loss).

Comment: I have 5V 2.5 and 1 A Power Supplies and I tried on both (first that stronger), on both the same situation :/ I have 10 cm cable XD Btw. 2 SD Cards corrupt exactly the same, in the same time ?

Comment: are you using the exact same downloaded image then? The corruption might be in there. 
(PS: when using a GUI in some OS's on the Pi2 models [not sure on other models] you see a rainbow square in the upper right corner, this indicates that the Pi isn't getting enough power)

Comment: I'm using exactly the same image fresh downloaded from raspberrypi.org ... I didn't see that square